# Floating menu for IE 9 Quirks document mode not working

Tags: css, menu

I have the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  margin: -2.5em 0 0 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background: hsla(80, 90%, 40%, 0.7);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: left;
  border: solid hsla(80, 90%, 40%, 0.5);
  border-right: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black;
  border-radius: 3em 0.5em 0.5em 3em;
}
#menu li { margin: 0 }
#menu a { color: inherit }

/* Make menu absolute, not fixed, on IE 5 & 6 */
#menu { position: absolute }
*>#menu { position: fixed }

p.stb { text-indent: 0; margin-top: 0.83em }
p.mtb { text-indent: 0; margin-top: 2.17em }
p.ltb { text-indent: 0; margin-top: 3.08em }
</style>
```

I used the following in my HTML code:

```
<ul id=menu>
  <li><a href="#L384">Section 1</a>

  <li><a href="#details">Section 2</a>

  <li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a>
</ul>
```

It cannot work in IE 9 Quirks document mode. However, when I change to IE 9 Standards document mode, it works perfectly.

How do I make my above code work in IE 9 Quirks document mode?

Comment: The real question is why on earth do you want to use quirks mode???

Comment: @Spudley, The real answer why on earth I want to use quirks mode is because my customer want backward compatibility and they also want modern design. If I change to IE 9 Standards document mode, part of the web page will be display wrongly. Currently, the only part that display wrongly is the float menu if used IE 9 Quirks document mode.

Comment: they can't have both. backward compatibility all the way back to IE5 is crazy anyway, but even if you do want it, being compatible IE5 obviously precludes the concept of modern site design. The main thing about QuirksMode vs standards mode are the box model differences. This is usually fairly easy to fix; it's just a case of adjusting margins, padding and border to suit the std model rather than quirks model. And if you can't do that there is a work around, in the form of [`box-sizing:border-box`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Comment: @Spudley I fully agree your point that they can't have both and as you know customer always think that everything in the IT world can be done. LOL! By the way, how does the `box-sizing:border-box` help my floating menu work when using IE 9 Quirks document mode (the menu remain floating and visible when the user scroll up or down)?

Comment: `box-sizing` is a way to use the quirksmode box model in standards mode. It means you can switch to std mode but not have to change your old quirks box model code; you just add `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` to your CSS and switch to standards mode; no-one will notice the difference (except users of IE6/7 which don't support it, [but you can polyfill that](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill)). So with that, you now don't need QuirksMode at all even for backward compat (unless you really do need it to work in IE5???), and thus your other quirks mode problems are no longer an issue.

Comment: @Spudley. Strange enough, it still does not work even I have included the `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` to my CSS. I do not know whether if it was a `SharePoint` problem (since the code that I was doing was inside SharePoint Designer).

Comment: at this point, I think we're going beyond what I can achieve using SO comments. Hopefully I've convinced you that quirks mode is unnecessary, which means we've gone beyond the scope of the original question. I suggest using the browser's dev tools to look at the CSS that is being applied to try to work out what the browser is or isn't doing re `box-sizing`. Beyond that, I'd need to see some code in action to be of much help, and it would probably warrant asking a whole new question.

Comment: @Spudley Yeah sure, no problem with that since I am convinced by your answer that Quirks serve two purpose - one to support backward compatibility, second to use it by accident or intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quirks mode is a *very* old mode. It is basically a backward compatibility mode to emulate IE5.

IE5 was released a long long time ago, and CSS has changed a lot since then. IE9 has a good rendering engine that works with modern CSS code. But of course Quirks mode is trying to emulate IE5, so it deliberately removes the support for all the new CSS features.

Roughly half of the CSS code you've quoted it not supported in Quirks mode. You will never get modern CSS code working in quirks mode.

So the question is why are you using quirks mode?

There are two possible answers to this: Either you need to use quirks mode for some backward compatibility reason or you are getting into quirks mode by accident.

If you really *need* to use quirks mode, then sorry, but you can't use modern CSS.

But if you're getting into quirks mode by accident, then the answer is to put a valid doctype at the top of your html code. This will tell the browser not to use quirks mode. The best doctype to use is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Simply make sure that's the very first line of code in your HTML page, and IE will go into standards mode instead of quirks mode.

Hope that helps.

(ps - you might want to read [this blog post](http://spudley.com/blog/keeping-ie-in-standards-mode) that I wrote recently on the subject)